# Error after upgrade from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.2 in activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have upgraded from Rails 4 to Rails 4.2 following the official documentation.

By the way I have a bug to fix.

In my search controller I have:

```
@contents  = Content.published.search_by_text(@query)
  Content Load (248.7ms)  SELECT "contents".*, ((ts_rank(("contents"."tsv"), (to_tsquery('italian', ''' ' || 'ces' || ' ''')), 0))) AS pg_search_rank FROM "contents" WHERE "contents"."state" = $1 AND (published_at <= '2015-04-07 16:38:38.000591') AND ((("contents"."tsv") @@ (to_tsquery('italian', ''' ' || 'ces' || ' '''))))  ORDER BY published_at DESC, pg_search_rank DESC, "contents"."id" ASC  [["state", "published"]]

=> []

@contents.count
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
```

In Rails 4.0 it returns '0'. The issue of course is related to @comments.

```
@contents.class
=> Content::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

I add to_a and now it works.

```
@contents.to_a.count
=> 0
```

I want to understand why I need to convert to array the result of an active record query. What is changed in Rails 4.2?

Comment: You can consult changelog here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Try @contents.count(:all)